# Radius of hyperbolic circles in a tessellation

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, tessellations

Killing my boredom, I played a bit on Geogebra and started this uniform hyperbolic pattern consisting of 8 circles per vertex.

Considering my Poincaré disk model is of Gaussian curvature -1, and using if possible the circumference of a circle of radius $r$ being equal to $2\pi\sinh(r)$, what is the radius of the circles?

Bonus points if you can name this pattern.

[image: pattern]

Comment: The geodesic between two adjacent nodes is the side of an equilateral hyperbolic triangle with angles $\pi/4$, $\pi/4$, $\pi/4$. Check here at the "Equilateral triangle" to get the side length: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_triangle

Comment: I get a side length of $2 \cosh^{-1} (\sqrt{\frac{2+\sqrt{2}}{2}})$.

Comment: This is related to the order-8 triangular tiling (observe the nodes) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order-8_triangular_tiling. As for the involvement of circles, the closest I could find is http://www.astro.ucla.edu/~wright/cosmo_art.html.

Comment: I'm a little unsure of the point of your post. Are you posing a puzzle for all of us to work on? If so, this is not a puzzle site, this is a site for mathematical questions.

Comment: @LeeMosher Not a puzzle at all, it was a genuine question (two questions, actually) to which I don't know the answer.

Comment: @D.Thomine - That is more simply $\text{arcosh}(1+\sqrt2)$.